# Consider rolling a die twice. Let X be the number of times (0, 1 or 2), that the number facing up was larger than 2. Find E[(2+X)^-1]

Tags: probability, expected-value

I understand that I first construct a table: where 0, 1, 2 represents `n` and `1/9`, `4/9` and `4/9` are their respective probabilities. Multiplying each `n` with its respective probability gives me the expected value `E(x) = 12/9`.

From here, how can I find `E[1/(2+X)]`? There is no `x` variable that I can manipulate. I general, for questions like this where we change the function `x` inside `E(x)` to something else, how can I solve them? Thanks!

Comment: Ahh sorry, I did not notice that, thanks! But after obtaining the probabilities 1/9, 4/9 and 4/9 I get an expected value of 12/9. How can I work with this value to get E[1/(2+X)]?

Comment: Just take the weighted average of $1/(2+X)$, as a sum over the possible values of $X$.

Comment: I agree with @mjqxxxx and in fact, my answer does represent a weighted average.  The weights are the respective probabilities of each of the occurrences $(x=0), (x=1),$ and $(x=2).$  Here, there is no need to *normalize* the weights, because the respective probabilities (i.e. the weights) already sum to $(1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My knowledge of Probability theory has cobwebs on it, so this is an intuition based response.

---

The first issue is : how to calculate the expected number of rolls that come up with a number higher than $2$.

That would be $$\sum_{x=0}^2 xp(x)$$

$$ = [0 \times (1/9)] + 
[1 \times (4/9)] + [2 \times (4/9)]$$

$$ = (12/9).\tag1 $$

---

I am going to use (1) above as a model for attacking the specific problem.

The pertinent function is $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{2+x}$.

Then, the expected value of $f(x)$ is

$$\sum_{x=0}^2 f(x)\times p(x)$$

$$ = 
[(1/2) \times (1/9)] + [(1/3) \times (4/9)] + [(1/4) \times (4/9)]$$

$$ = (17/54).$$

Comment: Thanks for this!